# java Exceptions Enter String only

Tags: java, try-catch

How to catch integer if the user must input String only, no integer and Symbols included to the input? Help me sir for my beginner's report.

```
import java.util.*;
public class NameOfStudent {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name = "";

        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        name = input.nextLine(); // How to express error if the Strin contains
                                //integer or Symbol?...

        name = name.toLowerCase();

        switch(name)
        {
        case "cj": System.out.print("Hi CJ!");
        break;
        case "maria": System.out.print("Hi Maria!");
        break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regular expression.

**Check if a String contains number/symbols etc..**

```
boolean result = false;  
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$");  
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("fgdfgfGHGHKJ68"); // Your String should come here
if(matcher.find())  
    result = true;// There is only Alphabets in your input string
else{  
    result = false;// your string Contains some number/special char etc..
}
```

**Throwing custom exceptions**

[Throwing custom exceptions in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574906/throwing-custom-exceptions-in-java)

**Working of a try-catch**

```
try{
    if(!matcher.find()){ // If string contains any number/symbols etc...
        throw new Exception("Not a perfect String");
    }
        //This will not be executed if exception occurs
    System.out.println("This will not be executed if exception occurs");

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

I just given a overview, how try-catch works. But you should not use a general "Exception" ever. always use your customized exception for your own exceptions.

Comment: is there any way i can use try-catch exception to this prob?

Comment: why you want to throw the exception?

Comment: See the link, try to have your custom exception, and put that in your else part.

Comment: sorry sir, our lesson talks about try-catch-finally! but my task is to discuss how it works if inputted data contains integer when String is needed. i gave up already dont know what to do...

Comment: I just given a overview, how try-catch works. But you should not use a general "Exception" ever. always use your customized exception for your own exceptions.

Comment: wow! so theres no Exception for Integer error? i guess i gotta do this. thanks sir =D

Comment: @user2763766 The exception makes sense if the problem is phrased the other way around. You get an input that u expect to be an number. Then it is possible to use an Integer.parseInt which would throw exception if there are string characters....

Answer (score 1):

Use `Regex` which is a sequence of characters that forms a search pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ABCD");
System.out.println("Input String matches regex - "+matcher.find());
```

**Explanation:**

```
^         start of string
A-Z       Anything from 'A' to 'Z', meaning A, B, C, ... Z
a-z       Anything from 'a' to 'z', meaning a, b, c, ... z
*         matches zero or more occurrences of the character in a row
$         end of string
```

If you also want to check for empty string then replace * with +

---

If you want to do it without `regex` then:

```
public boolean isAlpha(String name) 
{
    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) 
    {
         if(!Character.isLetter(c)) 
         {
                return false;
         }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You used a '*' in "^[a-zA-Z]*$". Due to that even if its a empty string like "", It will say its have a match. and I think name can't be a empty string.

Comment: @surender8388: OP doesn't have any problem with empty string. He just want to detect Numbers and Special symbols.

Comment: it seems difficult to explain 2 my classmates sir, can i do it in a try-catch Exception?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the String in your hand, e.g. name you can apply a regexp to it as follows.

```
    String name = "your string";
    if(name .matches(".*\\d.*")){
        System.out.println("'"+name +"' contains digit");
    } else{
        System.out.println("'"+name +"' does not contain a digit");
    }
```

Adapt the logic checks to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that a string can contain numeric character, and **it's still a string**:

```
String str = "123";
```

I think what you meant in your question is "How to enforce alphabetical user input, no numeric or symbol", which can be easily done using regular expression

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$"); // will not match empty string
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
bool isAlphabetOnly = matcher.find();
```

Comment: is there any way i can use try-catch exception to this prob sir?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as follows.

```
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]*$");// This will consider your 
                                                input String or not 
    Matcher m=p.matcher(name);
    if(m.find()){
        // your implementation for String.
    } else {
        System.out.println("Name should not contains numbers or symbols ");

    }
```

Follow this link more about [Regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). And test some regex by your self from [here](http://regexpal.com/).

Comment: But why? Without explanation, this is just garbage, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you formulate what the String is allowed to contain in a regular expression. Then you check if the String contains the allowed sequence - and only the allowed sequence.

Your code looks like this. I've added a do-while-loop to it:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = "";

    do { // get input and check for correctness. If not correct, retry
        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        name = input.nextLine(); // How to express error if the String contains
                                //integer or Symbol?...

        name = name.toLowerCase();
    } while(!name.matches("^[a-z][a-z ]*[a-z]?$"));
    // The above regexp allows only non-empty a-z and space, e.g. "anna maria"
    // It does not allow extra chars at beginning or end and must begin and end with a-z

    switch(name)
    {
    case "cj": System.out.print("Hi CJ!");
    break;
    case "maria": System.out.print("Hi Maria!");
    break;
    }
```

Now you can change the regular expression, e.g. to allow names with asian character sets. Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) how to handle predefined character sets. I was once checking any text for words in any language (and any part of the UTF-8 character set) and ended up with a regular expression like this to find the words in a text: `"(\\p{L}|\\p{M})+"`

Answer (score 0):

if we want to check that two different user enter same email id while registration.....

public User updateUsereMail(UserDTO updateUser) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        System.out.println(updateUser.getId());

```
    User existedUser = userRepository.findOneById(updateUser.getId());
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findOneByEmail(updateUser.getEmail());
    if (!user.isPresent()) {
        existedUser.setEmail(updateUser.getEmail());
        userRepository.save(existedUser);
    } else {
        throw EmailException("Already exists");
    }

    return existedUser;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;

    System.out.println("enter your name => ");
    name = s.next();

    try{
        if(!name.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+$")){
            throw new Exception("is wrong input!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("perfect!");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

umm..try storing the values in an array..for each single value , use isLetter() and isDigit() ..then construct a new string with that array

use try catch here and see !
i am not used to Pattern class ,use that if thats' simpler

Comment: That would be a horribly Rube Goldberged code. I would shout at the guy who wrote such.

Comment: sarcasm ??
not really familiar with  Rube Goldberged .but a quick google search showed me something to do with brilliant ideas ;)

Comment: Sorry if it sounded harsh, but having had dealt with unmaintainable code (some of what actually I wrote, and would have slapped even myself for it with my own severed arm), this is a very sensitive spot of mine...

Comment: ive done it sir, but my prof wants me to discuss it as try-catch exception.. sorry sir

Comment: but suppose the pattern class was not there, or some one never chanced upon it , or maybe someone was very new to java ,then this method is quite plausible ..

Comment: @user2763766 you could have easily integrated try catch with my naive /primitive program