# java exception catching in a different class than throwing

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have been working on a code that does 2 things:

1. Has a class that performs computations (logic)
2. has a class that displays the result.

I am wondering if it is possible to use try/catch statements in the Display class, where I would attempt to catch exceptions originating in the logic class.

Where Display would execute a line similar to logic.execute(input);

I was able to create a custom exception class where the following is placed in display class:

```
try{
logic.execute(input);
}catch(CustomException e){
//print statements
}
```

However I would like to be able to print exactly the error that occured, such as NullPointerException.

When i say print, i mean output in console. (but it must originate from display class)

If such a monstrosity is possible, please let me know.

Thank You guys!

Comment: [How to Throw Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) and [`Throwable#printStackTrack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace())

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.
You will need your custom exception class to extend `RuntimeException` instead of `Exception`, or the compiler will complain that you are not catching the exception that you throw.

See this post: [Throwing custom exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574906/throwing-custom-exceptions-in-java)

Simple working example:

```
public class ExceptionTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SomeClass myObject = new SomeClass();

    myObject.testFunction();
  }
}

public class SomeClass
{
  private SomeOtherClass someOther = new SomeOtherClass();


  public void testFunction()
  {
    try{
     someOther.someOtherFunction();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{

  public void someOtherFunction()
  {
    throw new CustomException("This is a custom exception!");
  }
}

public class CustomException extends RuntimeException
{
  public CustomException(String message)
  {
    super(message);
  }
}
```